# wordpress check if value exist in array

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to compare one input field i get from submit form, But even if number is correct it won't echo success.

```
global $wpdb;

$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['surname'];
$kunde = $_POST['kunde'];
$login = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT kunde FROM wp_kundenumber", ARRAY_N );
$kunde_string = end(explode(' ', $kunde));



if(in_array($kunde_string, $login)){

echo "succes";
}
 else {
echo "failure";
}
```

EDIT: these are var dumps of variables:

for `kunde_string` it says `string(6) "100001"`

and `$login` is a big array `array(9807) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "100001" } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "100002" } [2]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "100003" }...`

Comment: @FrayneKonok, OP is using `end()`; it should be a string.

Comment: for kunde_string it says ' string(6) "100001" ' and $login is a big array array(9807) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "100001" } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "100002" } [2]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "100003" }...

Comment: Add them into the question

Comment: The `$login` is a multi-dimensional array, you need single-dimension for `in_array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `array_map` php function instead of foreach loop, then use `in_array` to find value..

```
$login = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT kunde FROM wp_kundenumber", ARRAY_N );
$dataArray = array_map(function ($arr) {return $arr[0];}, $login); //will return single dimentional array of value at 0 index in $login items
if(in_array($kunde_string, $dataArray)) ///then in_array will work for you.. to find $kunde_string
{
    echo "Succes";
}
else 
{
    echo "Failure";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check `in_array` with `foreach`

Try as follows

```
 global $wpdb;

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['surname'];
    $kunde = $_POST['kunde'];
    $login = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT kunde FROM wp_kundenumber", ARRAY_N );
    $kunde_string = end(explode(' ', $kunde));
    $flag = false; 
        foreach($login as $value)
        {
            if(in_array($kunde_string, $value, true))
            {
               $flag = true; 

            } 
        }
        if($flag == true){

              echo "succes";
        }else {
             echo "failure";
        }
```

Comment: now it's working but now i get succesfailurefailurefailurefailurefailurefailurefailurefailurefailurefailurefailurefailurefailurefailurefailurefailurefailure.